# ADF Web Application: how to add and modify UI components on page loading (before it's displayed)?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I would like to know which are the different available approaches  to **add**, **modify** and **delete** UI components before a page loaded.

A practical example that I should handle is the following:

In my ADF Fusion Web Application (developed with JDev12.1.3) there are the pages login.jspx and main.jspx: if the user logs in correctly navigation to main.jspx happens.

In main.jspx there is an empty menu bar that at runtime I would like to fill with menus and menu items when the page loads, in function of the logged in user.

In the same page, in function of the logged in user, I also would like to add at runtime some UI components (output texts, buttons, ...) whith the chance to set their properties.

Could you kindly advice me which approaches I can follow to accomplish these duties?

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches. Use addChild() and related methods to physically add/remove menu items, or have the menu pre-built and use the visible property to show hide items.
As far as making this happen in custom code, you can use a Backing Bean (Managed Bean) that contains the code to determine what items to add/remove or make visible based on whatever criteria you choose. To call this code, you can 1) use the Invoke action in the rebinding layer - have it call the desired backing bean method - make sure to drag the Invoke action the TOP of the executables list. This is  the older, less preferred method. The newer, more preferred method is to add the backing bean method to the Task flow and have it navigate to the deserted page. This method can be part of the navigation form another page. Ex: After successful Login, navigate to your method an chav sit navigate to the Main page. The method will execute before the page loads and will set values to have the items added or visible or not.

```
RichSelectOneChoice choiceList;
       List child = choiceList.getChildren();
       child.clear();
       for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++){
           child.remove(i);
       }

       if ("1..1".equalsIgnoreCase(ccCode)){
           UISelectItem addChild = new UISelectItem();
           addChild.setItemLabel("1..1");
           addChild.setItemValue("1..1");
           child.add(addChild);

       } else if ("0..1".equalsIgnoreCase(ccCode)){
           UISelectItem addChild1 = new UISelectItem();
           addChild1.setItemLabel("0..1");
           addChild1.setItemValue("0..1");
           child.add(addChild1);
           UISelectItem addChild2 = new UISelectItem();
           addChild2.setItemLabel("1..1");
           addChild2.setItemValue("1..1");
           child.add(addChild2);

       }
```

Have you posted this question to he ADF forum, [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=83)?

Comment: Joe, for me it's clear how to work with a pre-built menu but it's not clear how to work starting from a menu that has only a menu bar. In my bean I need to reference the menu bar by a variable bound to the UI component: the problem seems to be that bindings between variables in the bean and UI components are accessible only after the page is loaded. I don't know if the use of @PostConstruct could workaround this "limit"...

Comment: this post might help: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/creating_dynamic_adf_input_forms, and this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3559961?start=0&tstart=0 and this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/48-sitemenu-protection-169190.pdf. short that you might have to read the docs on addchild as I said. this code might help too..

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the `rendered` attribute? Based on the condition the components will be rendered or not.

Comment: If I use the Render property perhaps - someone could confirm this? - I have to wrap each menu node in a group layout component. However kindly re-read my question and try to answer ;-)

Comment: The `rendered` property is easy to understand. If the condition is true, the component is rendered. Build your menu with all the possibility in your jsff and then condition all nodes with `rendered` property. When the page is loaded, the server will render only the components where rendered is true. You don't add components, you just render them or not.

Comment: Ok Sidney, thanks for your advice. But as regards the approach to programmatically create (on page load) a menu starting from an empty menu bar... what could you tell me? In general, I'd like to know - as I asked - <<how to add and modify UI components on page loading>>-

Comment: Why Rendered? why not set visible to false? Rendered is usually reserved for secure components to prevent the html for being generated - and therefore can cause other issues.

Comment: Why rendering components you won't need? `visible` is used when you  want to show/hide components dynamically based on user action.

Answer (score 1):

Personally the two approaches i've used on my works where:

1. Using the beforePhaseListener on the f:view component. Example: [Before Phase on JSF page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://oraclejdeveloperadf.blogspot.com/2012/03/executing-beforephase-code-on-jsp-page.html). But it might cause you some problems when taking account of adf lifecycle, especially if you have integrated parts (or even some simple jQuery components...).
2. And i think this would just do fine in your case, use a f:event component of type "*preRenderComponent*". Example: [How to use prerendercomponent](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-use-prerendercomponent-event-in.html). I suggest this second option 
Note: It's true that these aren't ADF Faces components, but since it's built on top of JSF, they work as they should. I can assure you they do work on 11g and don't expect any problems on 12c.

Comment: Hallo Endrik, thanks for your suggestion. I'm interested in using f:event. Could you kindly share a simple ADF Web Application in which a menu bar is filled at runtime when the page loads? If I would fill e.g. a panelGroupLayout I guess the approach is similar. In particular I'm interested in the code in the bean. Thanks.

Comment: There are known issues with non-ADF Faces components not working with ADF Faces components on the same page. I agree that looking at using a BeforePhase Listener might be good.

Comment: @Flattit82 , sorry i don't such a sample, but you can follow this one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/108-triggerpopupinregion-1994836.pdf  ,which is fairly similar. The way i think you should work wouldn't with dynamically generating the menu components, but hide/show them during runtime.

Comment: @Joe ,it's true for other libraries, but these are JSF native components, since ADF is built on top of it, i don't expect any problem, and i've personally used them with no problems (as i've stated on my answer)